# Why is w considered a consonant?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, consonants

I've always been taught that the character "w" in English was a consonant, except in very specific cases. However, on a recent trip to Wales, I learned that in Welsh it was considered a vowel. And then it struck me:

#### Is W really a consonant?

Whenever we (or, at least I) pronounce the character, I pronounce it as `oo` (as the Welsh do), such as in `whenever` (oo-ehn-eh-vehr). Does the `w` just signify a movement in pronunciation to or from `oo` and therefore act like a vowel, or is it something about the definition of a consonant?

Comment: It's called a *semivowel.* Basically, it's like a vowel, but it is used like a consonant in the English sound system. We have pairs of words like "wet" and "set," which have the same consonant-vowel-consonant structure. The letter "y" also often represents a semivowel in English; it's the equivalent of "ee". There are other questions about this; search for "semivowel" to find some.

Comment: @sumelic But what characteristics of it make it not a vowel entirely?

Comment: Syllable structure. We can distinguish between "swing," with one syllable, and "sueing," with two. (If you say "syewing," imagine a hypothetical word "soo-ing.") tchrist's answer here might be helpful: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/293443/77227

Comment: @sumelic Actually, that helps a lot. Could you add all of that information in as an answer so I can accept it later?

Comment: I’m afraid that *w* is neither a consonant nor a vowel; it is merely a letter. What sound it represents varies by language and word. For example, in the English word *whole* it represents no sound at all. Welsh uses seven letters for vowels: *a, e, i, o, u, w, y*.  I know you think you know what letters are, but even here Welsh will  confuse you: words like *twll* and *Llŷr* have only three letters in Welsh, and something like *Rhuthun* has only five letters.  That's because things like *ll* and *rh* and *th* ***are each single letters in Welsh!***

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: English is not Chinese. Or Indonesian, or Turkish, or Spanish. Why did you not ask, "why can't English pronounce X, J, G like Spanish does?" I mean why pick and choose Welsh vs English?